# send_mail() got multiple values for argument 'fail_silently' Django contact form only passing message not name or subject

Tags: python, django, forms, sendmail

So I'm trying to make a contact form with django, but it works but only with the message, I'm trying to have an area for the senders name and their email as well.

here's my working code in my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings



def index(request):

   if request.method == 'POST':
       message = request.POST('message')
       send_mail('Contact Form',
        message,
        settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        ['myemail@gmail.com'], 
        fail_silently=False)
   return render(request, 'app/index.html')
```

and the html

```
<h3>Contact Form</h3>

<form method="post" action="{% url 'index' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name." />
    
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and if I try to set

```
name = request.POST.get('name')
```

underneath the message = request.POST.get('message')
and then name after message in the send_mail function
I get the error `send_mail() got multiple values for argument 'fail_silently'` 
I've checked out the documentation and I've seen several different things but nothing worked the way I needed.

Comment: You have to put the name either in the message or the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way of doing it is to create HTML page for mail formatting. And pass all the data in that HTML page. This HTML format can be used as a message in send_mail 'html_message' field. Please check the below snippet for the same :

**views.py:**

```
def index(request):

   if request.method == 'POST':
       message = request.POST.get('message')
       name = request.POST.get('name')
       ctx = {
           'name' : name,
           'message' : message
       }
       message = render_to_string('mail.html', ctx)
       send_mail('Contact Form',
        message,
        settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        ['myemail@gmail.com'], 
        fail_silently=False, html_message=message)
   return render(request, 'app/index.html')
```

**mail.html :**

```
<body>
  <h1>This is HTML page for mail</h1>
  <p>{{name}}</p>
  <p>{{message}}</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Holy crap this is exactly what I needed Thank you so much!